# ExtJS6: How to set leftpad margin to 0 for treelist items

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a treelist working using ExtJS6 but since items are left padded automatically given their depth and text inside it gets truncated for third child and deeper. Since I use it as a menu, having fixed width. I need to remove auto calculated leftpad margin. I did not find anything useful while going through extjs api for treelist. Could anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code of `treelist` and `treelistitem` and abstract tree list item for a minute, you see that you can use the undocumented config property `indent:0` or the method `setIndent(0)`.

Not sure why it's not documented, presumably they intend to change the naming in future versions.

I have tested that it's working by opening [the dashboard example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard), expanding the "pages" subtree, and then putting the following line into browser console:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("treelist")[0].setIndent(0);
```

Comment: I tried using `indent` property on both `treelist` and `treelistitem`, none worked

Comment: @ducktyped Not sure what you did exactly, but I have updated the post with the reproducible results of my successful quick test.