# ExtJs - how can I find a specific config from code in the docs

Tags: extjs

Just started to take my first steps with ExtJs, however I cannot figure out this one, although it must be totally obvious. In the code below, the legend has a config called "docked", how can I find it in the docs?
I searched multiple ExtJs docs versions for it but I cannot find it.

What I do:

1. I see that we create an object of the class Ext.chart.PolarChart. So I go to the docs for this class.
2. There I see a config called "legend" of type Ext.chart.Legend. Then I go to the docs for this class. But there is no config called "docked".

I assume that ExtJs docs show also inherited configs. I also looked for some more specific Legend class, thinking that the one listed in the docs is a parent class of other legend classes, but I could not find any other matching classes. For sure I am missing some JS or ExtJs concept, I just can't figure it out.

What is the correct way to figure out where the legend config "docked" comes from/is defined?

```
var donut = Ext.create('Ext.chart.PolarChart', {
title: 'Test',
animation: true,
width: 300,
height: 300,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

store: storeA,

legend: {
    docked: 'bottom'
},

series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    angleField: 'value',
    colors: ["#9aff4f", "#35b4e3", "#ffb400"],
    donut: 20,
    label: {
        field: 'name',
        display: 'inside'
    },
    highlight: true
}]
```

});

Answer (score 1):

I think you did nothing wrong. You're entirely correct to search for "docked" in `Ext.chart.Legend`, and doing this for other configs should result in a hit with high probability.

But there are two things:

- Other programmers can always put configs into their component definitions that are wrong and do nothing. It could be that they wanted to write `dock: "bottom"`, did it wrong, but for some reason didn't see their error in the results, because the legend does what it should. You should definitely try what happens when you comment away that line. Does the legend change? (This is easy with `docked`, which should directly affect layout, but could be less easy with more obscure configs)
- Not all possible config properties are public, and therefor documented. `legend` has a hierarchy and mixins, so if that config shows any effect, you will have to manually check the code of all components in the hierarchy and all mixins whether any of the components looks into a `docked` property.
- Components are javascript objects, they allow for so-called expansion: if you add a config that is not processed, you can reasonably expect that the component has that property afterwards, which can then be processed from inside your code (outside of the component itself). For reasonably big code, you should start to put all such expansions into custom components, and use jsducks to generate a HTML documentation on these custom classes with their custom configs.

Comment: For point #2 the default behaviour (I believe) is to show all mixins/inherited configs.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli only if they have been properly documented, which [isn't the case for all private properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239872/extjs6-how-to-set-leftpad-margin-to-0-for-treelist-items/38243286#38243286).

Comment: If it's not documented then it's not part of the API. At your own risk etc etc.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you very much for your answer. Now at least I see that there are some options for such a config to be valid although it is not visible in the docs. 
Meanwhile I got an idea what might be the cause for this particular situation with this config. The library Sencha Touch has had a class Ext.chart.Legend with a config 'docked'. Sencha Touch has been merged into ExtJs 6. So I guess there is some old code available, but it should not be used so it's not documented...? Any way I think it's strange

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I agree with you. If it's a legitimate property (config, method, property, event) of a class, then it should be in the docs.

Comment: Oh, BTW, this config is valid and works. Changing the config changes the appearance. I am using ExtJS 6.0.2